# Can i reset database to a certain state from my Java application?

Tags: java, database, postgresql, jdbc

I have a Java application connected to a PostgreSQL database using a JDBC connection.  I would like to have a method in the Java application that resets the database state to the one in my .sql file.

Does this method already exist ? If not, how should I go about making it ?

EDIT: The reason I'm asking is because I'm trying to have self-contained tests for my DAOs in my school project. Because it's a school project and it's not a requirement I'm avoiding the usage of hibernate/spring boot H2 solutions that I found on-line (a bit to complex for my level)

Comment: This smells like an X/Y problem. You married yourself to a particular solution, but it sounds really suboptimal and difficult. Why not describe the problem you are trying to solve. Is this for development purposes, so you can easily restore a database to a fresh state and redo tests?

Comment: Sounds more like an admin question. You can backup and restore your database as much as needed.

Comment: Regarding the edit, an in-memory H2 database is infinitely easier to setup than a full postgres instance, especially when your target is to essentially not have a persistent database but rather return to a baseline each time you re-run. That is precisely the problem that H2 solves and why something like Spring Boot defaults to using it for unit testing purposes.

Comment: @Gimby thanks for the comments, they really helped me out

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that. The following might be a viable solution:

- create a template database `my_template` and load your SQL file into it
- make the database inaccessible with

  ```
  ALTER DATABASE my_template ALLOW_CONNECTIONS FALSE;
  ```
- create your actual database with

  ```
  CREATE DATABASE mydb TEMPLATE my_template;
  ```
- then, if you want to reset the database, run

  ```
  DROP DATABASE mydb FORCE;
  CREATE DATABASE mydb TEMPLATE my_template;
  ```